# How score is calculated in solar in edismax algorithm?

Tags: solr, lucidworks

How score is calculated in solar in edismax algorithm?
I have idea of qf, pf, pf2, pf3 and mm. But I have no idea what is formula used to get score of query({!field f=query_s v=$q}).
I am using LucidWorks, I have added the screenshot for your reference. I need to know exact formula or algorithm in which qf, pf, pf2, pf3 makes their contribution in calculating the score. Algorithm with a proper example is really helpful for me.
[Screenshot of details parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNGim.png)

Comment: Append `debug=all` to your query and you'll see exactly what makes up the score of each document in your result.

Comment: I tried. But that part is abstracted in debug=all.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, it's the Lucidworks code that implements that stage that would have to add the "debug=all" value to its call to Solr.  It would also have to transfer the response to some part of the Fusion response.

It's likely easiest to just create the Solr query that the stage would create, and run it yourself, either through the Solr Admin UI or directly to the Solr endpoint.